# Can I Order a dataset in BY a field BUT with a 2 specific stringsets appearing last in SQL?

Tags: mysql, sql

I need to order a queried dataset by a field BUT with 2 strings(i.e. 'Chemistry','Physics' an observation on the field) appearing last

I tried ordering it with the IN function (excluding the 2 strings from the order)

```
SELECT winner, subject
  FROM nobel
 WHERE yr=1984
 ORDER BY case when subject IN ('Chemistry','Physics') then 2 else 1 end asc, winner

winner                subject
Richard Stone         Economics
Jaroslav Seifer       Literature
César Milstein        Medicine
Georges J.F. Köhler   Medicine
Niels K. Jerne        Medicine
Desmond Tutu          Peace
Bruce Merrifiel       Chemistry
Carlo Rubbia          Physics
Simon van der Meer    Physics
```

Comment: Whats wrong with current code ?? What you want ?

Comment: Thanks but this requires a little more than that. there's a subtle added requirement.

Comment: The code seems right  .. You have error?

Comment: If you let us see  a " little more than that"   could be that we can eval ..

Comment: yes, I do. Although I get. a table slightly varied.    like:                                           
         César Milstein Medicine
         Desmond Tutu Peace
    Georges J.F. Köhler Medicine
       Jaroslav Seifert Literature
          Niels K. Jerne Medicine
         Richard Stone Economics
       Bruce Merrifield Chemistry
           Carlo Rubbia Physics
    Simon van der Meer Physics

Comment: @YogeshSharma. I need to get the query result to be exactly as able in the question summary.

Comment: `ORDER BY case when subject IN ('Chemistry','Physics') then 2 else 1 end asc, subject, winner`

Comment: This was very helpful. correct. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you should add subject to

```
    SELECT winner, subject
    FROM nobel
    WHERE yr=1984
    ORDER BY case when subject IN ('Chemistry','Physics') then 2 else 1 end asc
        ,  subject, winner
```

Answer (score 0):

In MySQL, if you want the two to appear last, you can simply do:

```
ORDER BY (subject IN ('Chemistry','Physics')) asc, winner
```

MySQL treats booleans as numbers in an integer context, with 0 for false and 1 for true, so this puts the true values first.